# Pasting large amount of regular text in VS results in a few rows of very long lines. How can this be done with more convenient formatting?

Tags: visual-studio

I apologize if this has been already asked, but I tried searching thoroughly for a similar question but could find nothing.

Anyways, essentially I was just pasting a large amount of text into Visual Studio obtained from Lorem Ipsum, and upon doing that, I got two rows of very long text.
Is there a simple way of nicely pasting larger amounts of regular text (not code) while maintaining a nice formatting that remains within the screen area?
I tried checking some different options in VS, but couldn't find anything related.

Being new to VS and coding, I was wondering if someone potentially knows of a simple fix to this that I overlooked?

Thank you!